# How can the "Dry Brush" Filter from Adobe Photoshop can be implemented in C#?

Tags: c#, image, bitmap, photoshop

I am currently creating an application that needs to implement the "Dry Brush" Filter of Adobe Photoshop on a Bitmap.

I have absolutely no idea where to begin.

Here is an example of the original image and what i need the outcome to be:
(Since i am a new user i cannot directly post images)

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

*Alternatively i would like to have the image to look like an oil painting like you can see in the example.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The definition for a dry brush filter is "Dry Brush: It simplifies an image by reducing its range of colors to areas of common color".

Try going through the image, pixel by pixel, and if the pixel is a certain shade of green, just turn it into a general shade of green.